# How to communicate "very negative" parameter estimate in paper?

Tags: presentation

I'm currently writing a thesis and I have to interpret a coefficient estimate that's extremely negative compared to what I hypothesized.

How do I best communicate this? Describing it as `"very negative"` sounds a bit strange, but I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expected the estimate to be negative, you could say something like "As expected, the coefficient estimate was negative, but its magnitude was much larger than expected".

Answer (score 2):

I would just write almost exactly what you did: "the coefficient was much lower than expected". Or, "based on .... [previous research? pilot studies?], we expected the coefficient to be in range X-Y. However, the estimated coefficient turned out to be much lower".

Clearly, this is not statistics, and there is no statistical significance involved, but there you have it: statistical significance is not the same as significance, and even the best statistical tests need to be interpreted.

I would not go for testing the coefficient against the range X-Y; it might evoke the impression that you came up with it post hoc.

Comment: *more negative* would be better than *lower* as some readers might instead think *smaller*

Answer (score 0):

When the result is "non significant" you don't say "how much insignificant it is" besides quoting the p-value.

I think, that what you want to do, is to informally test *another hypothesis*, that the parameter *is significantly smaller than some chosen  by you threshold*. In that case you'd need to formally create another test for it (which in most cases would should be straightforward) and quote this new p-value (which we expect will yield significant result).

The bottom line is, that the classical statistics (contrary to common sense and every-day intuition) doesn't provide arguments for null hypothesis. It can only give arguments *against it*.

Take a look at Bayesian Statistics. Although much more difficult to implement, in the end it does provide arguments both for or against any tested set of hypotheses.

Comment: Great answer and more informative than the other one, but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Just because the coefficient is negative doesn't mean it's not-significant. I would imagine that regressing life expectancy on blood pressure would have a significant--but negative--coefficient. Also, people do sometimes indicate how "insignificant" a result is, particularly if it was hypothesized to be significant but just misses one of the classical thresholds.